# CryptoPP throws exception 0xC0000374 when destructor is called

Tags: c++, mingw-w64, crypto++

I am trying to implement a custom AES CTR-mode encryption/decryption based on CryptoPP.

However, even the [examples provided on their website](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CTR_Mode) throw an exception when the decryptor class is destroyed although encryption/decryption is successful. I have tried all the samples provided here that provides a destructor in the code.

This is what the debugger reports regarding the location of the exception:

[image: debugger report]

I am using MinGW 12.

Some other algorithms such as MD5 work without and problems. Is there a specific bug for my compiler?

I've cleaned up caches and removed all compiler flags. Simply copy-pasting the code from the website into the main function throws the same exception.

Even a code as simple as the following throws:

```
#include <cryptopp/aes.h>
#include <cryptopp/modes.h>
using namespace CryptoPP;

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    SecByteBlock key(16), iv(16);
    std::memset(key, 0xff, key.size());
    std::memset( iv, 0x88,  iv.size());

    AES::Encryption aesDecryption(key, key.size());
    CTR_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption ctrDecryption(aesDecryption, iv);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=%200xC0000374](https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=%200xC0000374) is a heap corruption.

Comment: @drescherjm yup, I know, but, why?

Comment: I just tested this code in msys2 with MinGW-13.1 and  the crypto++ package installed using pacman and I had no heap corruption so my guess is you have incompatible libraries.

Comment: @drescherjm Interesting. I've tried reinstalling some packages, removing caches, etc. but nothing changed. Can you share your build details e.g. cmakelists, compiler flags, ...?

Comment: `g++ main.cpp -lcryptopp` with crypto++ and MinGW installed  from `pacman` in msys2: [https://www.msys2.org/#installation](https://www.msys2.org/#installation)

Comment: @drescherjm Nope, still not working. I also am using MSYS2. Uninstalled and reinstalled everything, but still the same error occurs...

Comment: Maybe you have some type of dll conflict on your system caused by having multiple versions of the runtime dlls for gcc.

Comment: `std::memset(key, 0xff, key.size());` - how does this compile? As for the manual it should be `std::memset(&key[0], 0xff, key.size());`.

Comment: @drescherjm Usually copying the correct dlls to the same directoy as the executable works. Nvm, I already gave up on this & will temporarily use another library for aes-ctr until I find a permanent fix for this. Thanks for your ideas tho.

Comment: @273K g++-13.1 in MinGW installed from msys2 compiled it with `g++ main.cpp -lcryptopp` for me. I am not at home so I can't test with different compile flags.

Comment: No warnings or errors with `g++ main.cpp -Wall -lcryptopp`